# Can I temporarily pause the RDF bulk loading process for a while and then recover it back to process?

Tags: rdf, bulkloader, bulk-load, virtuoso, data-dump

I am currently bulk loading DBpedia and Freebase data dumps into the virtuoso open source edition v7 using the rdf_loader_run() procedure. The database is on our server and I have another graph IRI in Virtuoso running for an online service.The loading process largely effect the responsing rate of the service. Can I use the rdf_loader_stop() in isql to temporarily pause the loading threads and is it capable to recover back to the former status of loading process by running rdf_loader_run() command again?
The Official Wiki doesn't explain this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rdf_loader_stop()` will stop importing after files which are imported right now are finished.   The queue is actually left intact at this point. Strictly speaking, it just puts a flag, which import-processes check before proceeding to the next file in queue.

`rdf_loader_run()` will continue with the next files in queue

Comment: Isn't the command `rdf_load_stop()` instead `of rdf_loader_stop()` ?

Comment: I have suggested edits, but they have been rejected.

Answer (score 2):

`rdf_load_stop()` will stop importing, and you can restart it at any time by running `rdf_loader_run()` again.

If you need to brute force a stop, type `txn_killall(1)`.

You can check the status of your import by opening a new isql window and type the followng query: `SELECT ll_state, COUNT(ll_state) FROM load_list GROUP BY ll_state`

`ll_state = 0:` files not yet processed
`ll_state = 1:` files that are currently being processed
`ll_state = 2:` files that are completed

If you did a brute force stop, you'll have to change the ll_state=1 rows to ll_state=0 again to make sure they will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

`rdf_load_stop()` is what you are looking for. However, it just stops the **next** file from being loaded. The current file has to finish first.

It basically inserts a `##stop` file in the `db.dba.load_list` table, which (I guess) gets checked first before Virtuoso processes the next file in the `load_list`